# Not All Default Parameters Are Rendering

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, default-parameters

Can anyone tell me why one default parameter renders the default value while the other doesn't?

Take this Nav component and its' props being passed. The heading prop renders however the props inside of `navItems` array does not. It will console log as `undefined`.

Note: If I remove/comment out all the props inside `navItems`, the default values do render.

Component:

```
const Nav = ({
  heading = "This Default Value Renders!",
  navItems = [
    {
      id: 0,
      label: "This Value Does Not Render",
      subMenu: [
        {
          id: 1,
          item: "This doesn't either",
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
}) => {

return (
  <h1>{heading}</h1>
  {navItems.map(item => (
    <li>
      <a href="#">{item.label}</a>
      <ul>
        {item.subMenu.map(subItem => (
            <li>{subItem.item}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </li>
  ))}
)

}
```

Component used in parent component with props being passed.

```
<Nav
  // heading = "I am the heading",
  navItems = {[
    {
       id: 1,
       // label: "About",
       subMenu: [
         {
           id: 1,
           // item: "About Sub Item 1",
         },
         {
           id: 2,
           // item: "About Sub Item 2",
         },
       ],
     },
  ]}
/>
```

Comment: I tried to reproduce your example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-tree-h4ftx?file=/src/App.js and it seems to work for me.

Comment: hmm ok, I'll have to check my code on codesandbox and troubleshoot

Comment: @RémiDoreau I commented out `label: "About",` shouldn't the default prop value `This Value Does Not Render` display in the UI? https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-https-gdwb4?file=/src/App.js

Comment: In fact you are providing the `navItems` props to the component, so it will override all the default `navItems` array. If you want to be able to provide default value for a specific index-path in the array, I think this is not the right way to go. Could give me some details about what you are trying to do so that I can help you more simply ? Maybe we need to refactor the way the component and the `navItems props` work.

Comment: As long as that's the correct behavior. I was under the impression if nothing was passed to `navItems.subMenu.item` then the default value will render.

Comment: @RémiDoreau Here's a question. Take a look at codepen: https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-agnesi-94jbw?file=/src/App.js:647-889 
If I have another object inside `navItems` array, and don't provide `subMenu` object, than it throws an error. I thought default value would provide a "default value" thus not having the error? It looks it doesn't, how do I fix this?

Comment: I tried to edit my previous example to match your needs: https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-tree-h4ftx?file=/src/App.js